# A Vowel Shift Question

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, poetry, rhymes, great-vowel-shift

Two lines from Byron's *Don Juan*:

> 'T is said that Donna Julia's grandmamma
>
> Produced her Don more heirs at love than law.

This is the coda to an octave, the finalizing couplet, and it's supposed to rhyme. All of Byron's "Don Juan" is supposed to rhyme.

So let's agree on one thing: this is a rhyme, or was in Byron's time, anyway.

It's definitely not a "sight rhyme" (obviously). ust a rhyme. Probably a perfect rhyme, too (back in Byron's day poets strove to find perfect rhymes and mocked those who failed in that noble quest).

The question is: how did Byron pronounce them? Was it grandmamaw-law, or grandmamuh-luh, or grandmaMAR-LAR? Or what?

Comment: Who told you *Don Juan* is supposed to have perfect rhymes? I believe there are a number of near-rhymes in *Don Juan* (although Byron does a remarkable job of finding perfect rhymes for most lines).

Comment: Where do I say that it's supposed to? Instead of searching for something to cavil at, why don't you try to answer the question? It is a pretty good one, you know!

Comment: @sumelic: A bit of French influence there, maybe?

Comment: @Ricky: It's an interesting question. You say that "all of Byron's _Don Juan_ is supposed to rhyme." Could you cite a source?

Comment: @Tragicomic - Read it, and you'll see. You can't always rely on "sources": sometimes it's a good idea to learn things.

Comment: @Ricky: The sarcasm and condescension in your comment are unnecessary and not inoffensive. If you don't have sources, just say it. Also, when you say "supposed to," it is natural for others to ask who it is is doing the supposing.

Comment: @Tragicomic - No sarcasm and no condescension. Read the damn thing. You might like it.

Comment: @Ricky: The scare quotes enclosing the word _sources_ imply sarcasm. Your telling me that it's a good idea to learn things (as also the assumption that I haven't read Byron) is condescending.

Comment: @Tragicomic - I'm perfectly serious now. Okay? You. Should. Really. Read. That. Book. It's one thing to rely on sources (no quotes). It's quite another to learn something on your own and, having learned it, form YOUR OWN opinion. Sources can be wrong. Your opinion can be wrong too, but at least it's yours. When I say that "Don Juan" is composed entirely of rhymed verse, I know what I'm talking about because I've read it. And I believe (sincerely) that you should too. That way, you won't have to rely on any sources, some of which might prove to be questionable.

Comment: You are still being condescending (and very much so). Anyway, I think @sumelic's answer below (which I have upvoted) suffices to explain why I was puzzled at your supposition that all of _Don Juan_ is supposed to have perfect rhymes. I was curious to know who (other than you) supposed this. I have my answer and do not wish to engage you anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm puzzled at your assumption that Byron would have considered imperfect rhymes in some way beneath him—from what I can see, they're ubiquitous in this poem.

### Other apparent imperfect rhymes in just the first canto

I'll transcribe things according to modern standard British pronunciation. I don't know this was how Byron pronounced things; this is just to give a point of reference. I actually tried to look up info about Byron's pronunciation, but I didn't manage to find any previous description of it.

First canto:
He starts out right away rhyming "want" /wɒnt/ with "cant" /kænt/. Either this is not a perfect rhyme, or his low vowels were distributed differently from modern speakers.

Stanza I.V.: he rhymes "War" /wɔː(r)/ with "Trafalgar" (/trəˈfæl.ɡə(r)/ in common speech, but apparently it has been /træfəlˈɡɑː(r)/ or something similar in [other poets' work](http://www.nelsonandhisworld.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=469)). The options I see here: this is an imperfect rhyme, or the rounding of "a" to /ɔː/ after /w/ was not present in Byron's speech (for this word). He does rhyme "waters" with "daughters" in another poem, though (["There Be None of Beauty’s Daughters"](https://cherryblossomlovers.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/stylistic-features-in-lord-byrons-poem-there-be-none-of-beautys-daughters/)) so the second option seems somewhat unlikely to me.
Furthermore, these two words seems to form a rhyming triple with "popular," which I quite doubt had the primary stress on the last syllable even at this time in normal speech. So there's some evidence that Byron took some liberties with the pronunciation of words to make his rhymes.

Stanza V: rhyming triplet "Agamemnon," "same none," "condemn none." It's doubtful that he normally pronounced "same" as /sɛm/. Seems like another imperfect rhyme.

Stanza XIV: rhyming triplet "tongue," "song," "wrong."

Stanza XXV: rhyming triplet "good-for-nothing," "doting," "both in."

Stanza XXX: rhyming triplet "damning us," "magnanimous," "malus animus." It seems ***quite unlikely*** for me that these constituted a perfect rhyme in his speech; the transposition of the "m" and "n" in any of these three words (without being marked in the spelling!) is not a likely development, or an attested one as far as I know (outside of one-off slips of the tongue).

### It's probably a near rhyme of /grændmɑːmɑː/ and /lɔː/

Like [Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284255/a-vowel-shift-question/284290#comment632576_284255) says (and as we verified above), it wouldn't be the only near rhyme in the poem. The spelling suggests that the vowels are different; the current pronunciation suggests that the vowels are different. This is where the evidence points overall.

### But if it is a perfect rhyme, it might be "grandmammaw"

But, let's assume it was a perfect rhyme for Byron for the sake of argument. I'm almost certain that Byron did not pronounce "law" with the /ɑː/ sound found in words like *star*. By the process of elimination, I would conclude that *grandmamma* was meant to be pronounced with a stressed final syllable with the vowel quality /ɔː/. The spelling doesn't suggest that, but there are recorded cases of "maw" /mɔː/ being used as a term for mothers.

The OED's  online edition has the following to say about "maw":

> Chiefly U.S. regional (see discussion s.v. ma n.3), also Canadian, and
>   20th-cent. Scottish.

According to Wikipedia, Byron wrote the poem around 1820. So this is a bit of a long shot, actually.

Comment: Yeah, okay, good answer. Do read the poem, or at least the first three cantos: it's worth it.